# Xcode compiles the storyboard for each app target when changed

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

We have a big Xcode project with 9 different targets for our app. They differ in branding, API-url's, and other smaller differences.
They are all using the same files/classes/storyboard, and only certain build settings, bundleID, appGroups etc are different. The logic in code that separates them are simply prepro-macros in the same files.

When I change something in the Storyboard, it recompiles the entire storyboard. Since it's a pretty big storyboard, it takes a while. My problem is that it compiles for **each** target. So, when I make a change, it compiles the entire storyboard **nine** times, and it takes a very long time. Since it is the exact same storyboard shared between these targets, why can't it compile it once and share the compiled result?

Every time I change something visual in Storyboard, or every time I have changed something small in the storyboard and try to build/run a target to a device, it says this in the status bar:

```
Building "MyTargetOne":   | Compiling 1 of 1 Storyboard files
[...]
Building "MyTargetTwo":   | Compiling 1 of 1 Storyboard files
[...]
Building "MyTargetThree": | Compiling 1 of 1 Storyboard files
etc.
```

Even if I try to run a specific target, and that target is first in the line of compiling, it still compiles the rest of the targets before it considers the app successfully built.

How can I prevent this, and only build the one I'm running?
I know about Editor->Automatically Refresh Views, but that didn't really help, other than that it doesn't show what I'm doing in the storyboard.. It still builds all targets when I build/run.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a pain to play with the same files on different targets.

If your app deployment target is iOS8 and above, you can try creating dynamic framework([Cocoa Touch Framework](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial)) with your storyboard and link your target's binaries with it.